# Cpack не может найти правила для сборки

Tags: c++, cmake

Есть проект состоящий из подроектов (клиент и сервер). Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы cmake генерировал deb пакет для сервера. В cmake сервера прописал

```
install(TARGETS ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR DEB)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT sssss@yandex.ru)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON)
include(CPack)
```

Но в итоге генерируется deb пакет для всего проекта. Если его установить - то это будет просто директория с исходниками. А мне нужно исполняемый файл для сервера.

Что нужно дополнительно указать?

мой cmake проекта выглядит так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(AppChat)
set(DIR_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

set(PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME        protocol_lib)
set(LOGGER_LIB_NAME          logger_lib)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(${DIR_LIB}/protocol)
add_subdirectory(${DIR_LIB}/log)

add_subdirectory(${DIR_SRC}/server)
add_subdirectory(${DIR_SRC}/client)
```